# Render Vertical Line at specific date Line Chart

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, linechart, reportbuilder3.0

I was wondering if there was any way to render a vertical line at a specific point on the X axis of a line chart in Report Builder 3.0.  As you can see in the image, i Want to render a vertical line where all of the datapoints below come together and begin their decent.  In this case it would be at the "Jan 20" mark below.  I have tried using StripLines, but haven't been able to achieve my desired result.  Not sure I am using them correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@adam-bird's answer worked for me. To expand on it:

1. Click the Horizontal Axis.
2. Go to the Properties window -> StripLines -> click the ellipses.
3. Add a strip line.
4. In the StripLine properties: Interval.IntervalOffset = DateValue("SomeDate").ToOADate
5. In the StripLine properties: Interval.IntervalOffsetType = Days
6. In the StripLine properties: Interval.IntervalType = Days
7. In the StripLine properties: Interval.StripWidth = 1
8. In the StripLine properties: Interval.StripWidthType = Days

Answer (score 0):

I would add a StripLine to the Category/X-Axis. For IntervalOffset I would write an Expression to return the for of 20 Jan. For StripWidth I would try something like 0.1 (i.e. 10% as wide as 1 day).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add a StripLine to a specific date of your report is to use an expression similar to this one:

```
=DateValue("January 30, 2014").ToOADate
```